# Optimization problem involving VAR

Tags: time-series, optimization

I'm looking to solve, from the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.02176.pdf,

$$\min_{g\in VAR(p)} \sum_{z\in \mathcal{Z}} (f( h_{x}(z))-g(z))^2\pi_{x}(z)$$

where $\mathcal{Z}\in \\{0,1\\}^{N\times W}$ is the set of coalition matrices.

$\pi_{x}(z)$ is a Shapley kernel, $f$ is a prediction function, and $h_{x}(z)$ is a masking function that maps $x$ to $x_*$.

For all purposes, we can simplify this question to

"how do we solve a minimization problem
$$\min_{g\in VAR(p)} \sum_{z\in \mathcal{Z}} (f(z)-g(z))^2\pi(z)$$

where instead of searching over linear models, we're searching over VAR models?"

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you need to fit a VAR model for each lag, and then choose the lag where the objective function is minimized. I imagine you will only want to fit VAR models that are stationary as well so that will be an added complication.